# componentDidUpdate is one step behind the actual value in the setState

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React and chartJs to create some basic charts for a dashboard.

I want to implement a onClick functionality which will take the clicked element's data and update it in a AgGrid table.
I managed to do that but it appears that I have one problem: Whenever I click one element, it updates the values from the previous clicked element.
I understand that it has to do with the fact that setState is async and does not update at the moment when I click an element.
Any ideas?

below is my code:

```
handleChartClick = (element) => {
  if (element[0] !== undefined) {
    const { datasets } = element[0]._chart.tooltip._data;
    const datasetIndex = element[0]._datasetIndex;
    const dataIndex = element[0]._index;
    const dataLabel = element[datasetIndex]._chart.data.labels[dataIndex];
    const value = datasets[datasetIndex].data[dataIndex];

    //alert(`${dataLabel}: ${value}`);

    this.setState({
      tabledata: {
        columnDefs: [{ headerName: 'Service name', field: 'service', sortable: true, filter: true, resizable: true },
        { headerName: 'Running times', field: 'times', sortable: true, filter: true, resizable: true }],
        rowData: [{ service: dataLabel, times: value }]
      }
    }, () => {});
  }
}
```

In the Child class:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
     this.state.tabledata = this.props.tabledata;   
    }
```

Extra: I am using classes for the definition of chart Components and the App.

/// Later Edit:
Found the problem, when i was instantiating my AgGrid, instead of using this.props.smth, I was using the this.state.smth (the problem was that at the current point, the state has not been modified yet and it was referencing to old values).

Comment: share your whole component, btw why you did use this ? `this.state.tabledata = this.props.tabledata;` and didnt use `this.props` on table directly?

Comment: Yeap, it was a mistake I made, after re-reading the props and state documentation I realised how dumb this sounded.

Comment: does this solve the issue?

Comment: Yes, it did, thank you. :)